# How to replicate ArcGIS coordinate transformation with ogr2ogr?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ogr, coordinate-system

I need to be able to replicate with ***ogr2ogr*** a coordinate transformation that was executed in ***ArcGIS for Desktop***.

Both ArcGIS and ogr2ogr are based  on ***EPSG standard definition***.

There's not only one way to transform data from a reference system **A** to a reference system **B**, but many transformations are possible **(T1, T2 ... Tn**).

After a lot of reading i understood that EPSG codes define, among many other things, CRS (coordinate reference systems, A and B in the previous example), and possible transformation between them (T1...Tn).

When in gis one performs a coordinate transformation ArcGIS prompts the user with the choice of a transformation.
On the other side ogr2ogr simply works specifying the source and destination CRS.

two questions then arise:

- what kind of transformation does ogr2ogr performs? is it still based on the transformation defined within the epsg standard?
- Is it possible to force ogr2ogr to use a transformation specified via an epsg code?

please keep in mind that my goal is to replicate a transformation executed in gis (thus identified by an epsg code), with a call to ogr2ogr.

Answer (score 2):

ogr2ogr provides 3 command line options dealing with coordinate systems

```
-a_srs srs_def:
    Assign an output SRS
-t_srs srs_def:
    Reproject/transform to this SRS on output
-s_srs srs_def:
    Override source SRS
```

The one you are looking for it -t_srs to transform, though you may also need -s_srs if your source data does not have it's coordinate system set correctly

To specify a coordinate system by an EPSG code you can use the format EPSG:nnnn

for example to transform a shapefile to EPSG 4326

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp input.shp -t_srs EPSG:4326
```

Comment: Also, as @SaultDon notes, [ogr2ogr also recognizes ESRI .prj files](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/19767/4968) as inputs for these three arguments. There's some [additional reading on ogr2ogr projections](http://gothos.info/tag/gdal-ogr/) over at Gothos GIS blog that you might find useful.