# Tile server return empty features

Tags: postgis, web-mapping, geojson

I have successfully installed tilestache. I also has succesfully add a layer using shapefile from [here](http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/land-polygons). But when I tried to use [my own shapefile](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?sdfka6c0in0cac8), the server always return empty featurecollection. I have tried to add `ST_Transform()` in the query but still return empty feature.

My config file:

```
{
  "cache":
  {
    "name": "Test",
    "path": "/tmp/stache",
    "umask": "0000"
  },
  "layers":
  {
        "osm-processed_p1": {
            "allowed origin": "*",
            "provider": {
                "class": "TileStache.Goodies.VecTiles:Provider",
                "kwargs": {
                    "dbinfo": {
                        "host": "127.0.0.1",
                        "user": "postgres",
                        "database": "ts_data"
                    },
                    "queries": [
                        "SELECT gid, geom AS __geometry__ FROM osm.kalimantan"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Well, first thing, your shapefile doesn't have a .prj sidecar file to convey its projection. So I'm betting that's the trouble.

Comment: The shapefile is in WSG84. What if I don't have the .prj file? What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed your shapefile has no `.prj` sidecar file. If you have installed the GDAL/OGR toolkit, it could be worth a try to attach the projection information to see if that brings everything to life.

**Use ogr2ogr to fix it..**

Your data appears to be in WGS84 (i.e. EPSG:4326), so the following [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) command will [create a new version of your shapefile with a `.prj` file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/19767/4968):

```
ogr2ogr -a_srs EPSG:4326 "C:\path\to\output\kalimantan_4326.shp" "C:\path\to\input\kalimantan.shp"
```

**Or you can just manually fix it..**

In this case it might just be easier to add a `.prj` file manually. To do that, open notepad, paste the following text, and save the file to the same folder as `kalimantan.shp`. Make sure to name the new file `kalimantan.prj`:

```
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]
```

***Make sure you're saving the file as kalimantan.prj, and NOT kalimantan.prj.txt, which Windows may do if you don't have "Hide extensions for known file types" checked in Folder Options!***

My only remaining concern is that typically, when projection data is missing, open source GIS software will try to consume it as WGS84. But your data appears to be in WGS84, and that didn't happen. So I'm not 100% sure this will solve your problem--there may be another issue. I still think it's worth a shot, though.

Comment: still doesn't solve my problem.